# HTML/CSS Mutiple menu image buttons rollover in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have this problem with my navigation bar. I have 5 .png buttons horizontaly aligned. I want to give them rollover in CSS, not JAVA.

I tried so many things but just can't seem to control it. Al the ways I tried, it wont even load the images... I don't know what to do :) I already placed them in 1 big div. Here's my code:

```
<div id="img">
    <a id="anchor1" href="index.php" ></a>
    <img src="images/nav/spacer.png" alt="" class="btn"/>

    <a href="portfolio.php">
        <img src="images/nav/portfolio_btn.png" name="portfolio" width="128" height="51" border="0" class="btn" id="portfolio" alt="" />
    </a>
    <img src="images/nav/spacer.png" alt="" class="btn"/>
    <a href="diensten.php"><img src="images/nav/diensten_btn.png" name="bestellen" width="125" height="51" border="0" class="btn" id="diensten" alt="" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Show us the code that you have already please. Does the image load if you put it in the page as a full image or does it not load a t all?

Comment: <div id="img">
<a id="anchor1" href="index.php" ></a>
<img src="images/nav/spacer.png" alt="" class="btn"/>
<a href="portfolio.php"><img src="images/nav/portfolio_btn.png" name="portfolio" width="128" height="51" border="0" class="btn" id="portfolio" alt="" /></a>
<img src="images/nav/spacer.png" alt="" class="btn"/>
<a href="diensten.php"><img src="images/nav/diensten_btn.png" name="bestellen" width="125" height="51" border="0" class="btn" id="diensten" alt="" /></a>
</div>

If you want to see the website I dont know if I may give links but its vazcreations.nl

Comment: When I use the <img src> function in my html it loads perfectly only not when I try in css...

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you look into [CSS sprites](http://www.google.co.za/search?q=css%20sprites&hl=en&rlz=1C1SKPL_enZA434ZA434&num=10&lr=&ft=i&cr=&safe=active&tbs=,qdr%3am). Here's an example tutorial for a menu: http://praveenfrancis.com/tutorials/create-a-simple-menu-with-css-sprite/

Answer (score 0):

Try putting images inside of a `<a></a>` then in CSS declare something like this:

```
a hover{
background://what you want;
}
```

Comment: You mean like, <a href="#"><img src".." /></a> That I already have.
And I have 5 menu images, when I just use that wont all the images roll over as the same images?

Comment: yes, because you should have a separate `<div>` or `<span>` for each menu. like this `<div id='menu1'><a hre='#'><img.../></a></span>` and for css `#menu1 a:hover{...}`

Comment: Hmm let me see if it wants to work. I just hope the div's won't mess up my nav bar...

Comment: Oke this is what I now have//

HTML:<span id="home"><a href="index.php"><img src="images/nav/home_btn.png" border="0" alt="" /></a></span>

CSS:#home a:hover {
 background-image:url(images/nav/home_roll.png);
 margin-bottom:66px;}

Wont work :P

Comment: I'm sorry I can't follow you right now... Change the <span> for <div>, or ... ?

Thanks alot for your help!

EDIT SEEN! :D

Comment: ay, remove `<img>` you should put image in `<div>`: `<div id="home"><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></div>` and CSS: `#home a{width:\\image width; height:\\image height; background-image:\\normal image url;}` for hover `#home a:visited{width:\\image width; height:\\image height; background-image:\\hover image url;}`

Comment: Dude, I don't get it... I did everything you said but still no result.. 
`#home a{
 width:90px; 
 height:51px; 
 background-image:url(images/nav/home_btn.png);
 margin-bottom:66px;}

#home a:hover{
 width:90px; 
 height:51px;
 background-image:url(images/nav/home_roll.png);}`

Comment: `<div id="home"><a href="index.php">&nbsp;</a></div>`

And the div messesup my whole coding :P

Comment: No, I was actualy waiting for a comment from you :)

Maby I can send you the files and you can have a look yourself? Only if you have time and want to. If you don't, thats oke..

Comment: OK, zip all files and upload to a file sharing site like uploadmb.com

Comment: Oke done! Here is the link http://www.uploadmb.com/dw.php?id=1312454237

And I was working on the footer alswel so dont mention that. If you want a look on how I would like it, see www.vazcreations.nl/new

Thank you very much !

Comment: And what you think/find? And is the coding really terrible?

Comment: http://www.uploadmb.com/dw.php?id=1312456112 works in firefox and ie8 but i suggest you using javascript to change roll over image.

Comment: Hmm yeah I see in firefox it works.. But in chrome what I use it doesnt... Anyway thank you alot for you time and help.
I dont mind doing it in java only some people here tell me that if I can't get an image to rollover in css then im not qualified enough to make websites and it isnt coding 2011 style and stuff.. So thats why I want it in CSS but it just doesnt seem to happen.. Cuz in firefox it works now, but it should also work in chrome ect ect...

Comment: It works in chrome too, but when you move the pointer in top-left corner of image, try google may fix it

Comment: I guess i'll stick to the java script I used originaly on www.vazcreations.nl/new. W3C gives some erros but who cares :P

Thanks again!